# Output from a system of cascade connection with Wilkinson's divider and Quadrature hybrid

Tags: rf, quadrature, power-divider

[image]

So I have this system, with

\$f=3GHz\$

\$b = \frac{λ}{4}\$

\$a = 0<a<b\$

and I want to know the output at ports 2 and 3.

I'm wondering how exactly I should approach it, and if my sketch is anywhere close to the truth.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJZ0dz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm wondering if I can consider the schematic in parts, or if I'm forced to consider all components at the same time, and if there are some shenanigans (like transformations) that I need to perform first.

Comment: I'm not sure if you already know this or not, but a transmission line segment with a given Z0 is not the same as a resistor with resistance Z0. Sorry our schematic tool doesn't include a transmission line object, so you might need to use a better drawing tool to diagram this circuit.

Comment: Yeah, I only used resistor since there was no impedance component, I just hoped to make it as clear as possible by using the value as "Zn" instead of an actual resistance

Answer (score 0):

Is this what are you trying to get?

You may consider using Qucs. It includes a transmission line component.

http://qucs.sourceforge.net/download.html

[image]